# WebConfigurationManager is unrecognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a C#/MVC 4 noob in setting up connections. Until now, it's always been in place prior to me working on it, so I've never had to think about it. Now, however, I need to set up a secure connection to a database, and don't have any working examples to use as a guide.

I am currently trying to get the example found in the [SqlCredential documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to work, to no avail. They seem to have left a lot out in this implementation.

Is there perhaps a more complete guide to this that I should be aware of?

Here's my code:

```
// Web.config:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Con" connectionString="Initial Catalog=myDB;Server=\\Server_name" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

// SearchController.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient; // for SqlConnection & SqlCommand
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Security;

Configuration config = Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Null);
ConnectionStringSettings connString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionString[“Con”];

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString.ConnectionString))
{
    SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
    pwd.Equals("PASSW0rd");
    pwd.MakeReadOnly();
    SqlCredential cred = new SqlCredential("my_user_id", pwd);

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Search", conn);
    conn.Credential = cred;
    conn.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

There is an error on WebConfigurationManager:

> 'System.Configuration.Configuration' does not contain a definition for
>   'WebConfigurationManager'

There is an error on Null:

> The name 'Null' does not exist in the current context

And an error on ConnectionString["Con"]:

> 'System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection' does not contain a
>   definition for 'ConnectionString' and no extension accepting a first
>   argument...

Also, is there a better place to put my password and username? In the example it uses text boxes to accept these as inputs, but in my situation they are already known and won't change.

Comment: Try using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.    Also make sure your project is referencing the System.Configuration assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It thinks you are looking for the `WebConfigurationManager` inside the `System.Configuration.Configuration` **class**, not the `System.Configuration` **namespace**, try giving the full namespace:

```
Configuration config = System.WebConfiguration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
```

Also the `Null` is a typo, it should be `null`.

Comment: I tried System.Web.Configuration, and that worked, but ConnectionString still has the error.

Comment: Did you include the System.Configuration reference?

Comment: Yes (all my includes are with the code I provided).

Comment: I figured out the problem. In the code I copied from the MS site, it says ConnectionString. It needs to be ConnectionStrings. Apparently they don't test any of their examples. WTF?

Comment: @Tra: yes, it happens. And more often than you think. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my final, working outcome in case someone else had this same problem:

After watching the first 3 videos of [this great series on setting up .NET db connections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBCPc44CE74&list=PL6n9fhu94yhX5dzHunAI2t4kE0kOuv4D7&index=1), I was able to get a connection working. I'm not sure why the MS Documentation makes it overly-complex, but kudvenkat straightened me out:

```
// web.config   
<add name="MyDataConnection" 
     connectionString="data source=server_name; database=myDB; user id=my.user.iDB password=PASSW0rd"        
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>

// SearchController.cs
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Search", connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

Pointing out some important learning points:

- the connection string doesn't have to be in that elaborate ConfigurationStringsSettings object, it can just be a string.
- the password can be defined in the connection string in web.config
- you don't need to use System.Web.Configuration to get the Configuration String from Web.config